# Show Facebook Group Comments on website using php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am current displaying a facebook group page posts on our website using the following code:

```
<?php


$limit = 10; // The number of posts fetched
$access_token = 'enter token here';
$group_id = '3573401125';
$url1 = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$group_id.'?access_token='.$access_token;
$des = json_decode(file_get_contents($url1));


/**echo '<pre>';
print_r($des);
echo '</pre>';**/

$url2 = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$group_id}/feed?access_token={$access_token}";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url2));

//print_r($data);
?>

<div class="wrapperfb">
<!--<legend class = "dashheadlinetitle">Millbrook RFC Facebook Group</legend>-->
<div class="topfb">
    <a class="afb" href='http://www.facebook.com/home.php?sk=group_<?=$group_id?>&ap=1'>
    <?=$des->name?> Facebook Group</a>
        <div style="width:100%; margin: 5px">
        </div>
</div>
<?php
    $counter = 0;

    foreach($data->data as $d) {
    if($counter==$limit)
    break;
?>
<div class="singlefb">
    <div class="imgfb">
        <a class="afb" href="http://facebook.com/profile.php?id=<?$d->from->id?>">
           <img border="0" alt="<?=$d->from->name?>" src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?=$d->from->id?>/picture"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="textfb">
        <span style="font-weight:bold">
            <a class="afb" href="http://facebook.com/profile.php?id=<?=$d->from->id?>"><?=$d->from->name?></a>
        </span>
        <br/>
    <span style="color: #999999;">on <?=date('F j, Y H:i',strtotime($d->created_time))?></span>
    <br/>
    <a class="msglink" href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/3573401125/"><?=$d->message?></a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
    $counter++;
    }
?>
```

This works fine to show me the most recent posts to the group. I've searched through the FB Developer site and use google but can't seem to find a way to bring up the comments on each post.

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: I think [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17804145/how-to-get-all-post-from-a-page-with-count-all-likes-and-comments) could be very helpful. 

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to make a request for each post you get returned to https://graph.facebook.com/12345/comments/?summary=true where `12345` is the post_id.

Some pseudo-code to explain what I mean:

```
posts = fetchPostsFromFacebook(group_id)
foreach (posts as post)
  post_comments = fetchComments(post.id)
```